# ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken and @AuthenticationPrincipal

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, single-sign-on, saml

I have a little problem with an ADFS SSO and Spring Security integration.

The SSO Login works fine but when the `Authentication` Object is stored in session handled by Spring Security is of type `ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken` instead of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` even if It's a direct subclass, the problem is that The current user bound by `@AuthenticationPrincipal` into Controller methods is `null`.

I've implemented a `SAMLUserDetailsService` where I return a full `UserDetails` object.

Fork the sake of completness I've a full `UserDetails` user into `Principal` property of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` but only a String with "firstname lastname" into the same Principal object into `ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken`.

How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2):

I solved with forcePrincipalAsString = false in samlAuthenticationProvider